# Infinite series Sum of zeroth order Bessel Functions of first kind

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, bessel-functions, hypergeometric-function, poisson-summation-formula

I am trying to find the upper bound of
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} J_0(an) J_0(bn) \sin(cn) \sin(dn)
$$
where $J_0(x)$ is the zeroth order Bessel function of first kind, and $a,b \geq 0, \textit{ and } c,d \in \mathbb{R}$.
I have tried to use Poisson summation formula but without any success. Any kind of help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You can use an asymptotic expansion for the Bessel functions, $J_0(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos \left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$. Further use that $\sin(cn)\sin(dn) = \frac12 \cos[(c+d)n] -  \frac12 \cos[(c-d)n]$ and $\sin(A)\sin(B) = \frac12 \cos[A+B] +  \frac12 \cos[(A-B]$. This yields a finite sum of terms of the type $\frac{2}{\pi ab}\sum_n \frac{1}{n} \cos (k n) + \sum_{n} \mathcal{O}(n^{-2}) \cos (\ell n)$, where $\ell=c\pm d$, $k=a\pm b\pm c \pm d$ and the remainder term can be bounded by the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Note that $\sum_n n^{-1}\sin(nx)$ is related to the Heaviside step function.

Comment: Thanks bkocsis. But Riemann rearrangement theorem does not allow us to calculate the series sum of leading asymptotic term and error term separately.